# How to update object stored inside an SQLite DB

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, sqlite-net

I have a page where I want to edit an object and then update the object in the DB. I have this under this save button click event:

```
private async void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    p.ProductName = nameTextBox.Text;
    p.Price = double.Parse(priceTextBox.Text);
    p.Quantity = int.Parse(quantityTextBox.Text);
    p.Description = descTextBox.Text;

    if (data.UpdateProduct(p))
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Product changes updated", "UPDATE OUTCOME");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Product changes NOT updated", "UPDATE OUTCOME");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

The `UpdateProduct()` method is as follows:

```
public bool UpdateProduct(Product product)
{
    if (conn.Update(product) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever I attempt the edit the object the `UpdateProduct()` method returns false and the object doesn't get updated, I can't figure out why.

Product Class:

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Product ID: {this.Id}, Product Name: {this.ProductName}, Price: {this.Price}, Quantity: {this.Quantity}";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If this provides any more insight, the product is retrieved from the DB like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    int id = (int)e.Parameter;
    Product p = data.GetProductById(id);

    nameTextBox.Text = p.ProductName;
    priceTextBox.Text = p.Price.ToString();
    quantityTextBox.Text = p.Quantity.ToString();
    descTextBox.Text = p.Description;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `Id` of your product being not set when retrieved from the DB is that you set the `Id` property to as `private set`, which means SQLite cannot actually set the property value and hence it remains 0. Just remove `private` from the setter and everything should work fine :-) .

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Also note**: You are creating a local variable `Product p = data.GetProductById(id);` in the `OnNavigatedTo` override, which is a problem, because in the `saveButton_Click` method you are using another instance of `p` (I presume a field), which is then probably not initialized.

You need to make sure you use the same variable in both cases, to make sure the `id` you retrieved from the DB is set:

```
private Product _updatedProduct;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    int id = (int)e.Parameter;
    //assign to the private field
    _updatedProduct = data.GetProductById(id);

    nameTextBox.Text = _updatedProduct.ProductName;
    priceTextBox.Text = _updatedProduct.Price.ToString();
    quantityTextBox.Text = _updatedProduct.Quantity.ToString();
    descTextBox.Text = _updatedProduct.Description;
}

private async void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //update properties of the private field
    _updatedProduct.ProductName = nameTextBox.Text;
    _updatedProduct.Price = double.Parse(priceTextBox.Text);
    _updatedProduct.Quantity = int.Parse(quantityTextBox.Text);
    _updatedProduct.Description = descTextBox.Text;

    if (data.UpdateProduct(_updatedProduct))
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Product changes updated", "UPDATE OUTCOME");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Product changes NOT updated", "UPDATE OUTCOME");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

**Original answer**: 
`Product` probably has an `Id` column which SQLite uses to determine which row in the database should be updated. Make sure the ID of your product is actually set to an existing ID when you call `Update`.

Comment: You are correct, product does have an Id column. I added the product class to the original post.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the line `if (conn.Update(product) > 0)` to see if `product` has its `Id` set to some existing value and is not 0?

Comment: @jimbrowning I have updated my answer with the solution :-)

Comment: @jimbrowning I have updated my answer with new suggestion

Comment: Your new solution is correct! I was missing `private Product _updatedProduct;` and was therefore referencing two different product objects. Thank you for providing multiple solutions and sticking with me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome :-) , glad it helped! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`public int Id { get; private set; }` is your problem.

Remove the `private` accessor.

Comment: This hasn't worked, I have updated the original post to try and give more insight on my code. Thank you for the answer.